# Can't install any packages in pip nor upgrade it due to OSError

Tags: pip

This is the entire output for when I try `pip install numpy`

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/c5/21/275cfa7731ee2e121b1bf85ddb21b8712fe2f409f02a8b61521af6e4993d/numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/c5/21/275cfa7731ee2e121b1bf85ddb21b8712fe2f409f02a8b61521af6e4993d/numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/c5/21/275cfa7731ee2e121b1bf85ddb21b8712fe2f409f02a8b61521af6e4993d/numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/c5/21/275cfa7731ee2e121b1bf85ddb21b8712fe2f409f02a8b61521af6e4993d/numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/c5/21/275cfa7731ee2e121b1bf85ddb21b8712fe2f409f02a8b61521af6e4993d/numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/c5/21/275cfa7731ee2e121b1bf85ddb21b8712fe2f409f02a8b61521af6e4993d/numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

When I use `pip install numpy --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org` this is the output

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
     / 523.2 kB 1.6 MB/s 0:00:00
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/21/275cfa7731ee2e121b1bf85ddb21b8712fe2f409f02a8b61521af6e4993d/numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl:
        Expected sha256 a51725a815a6188c662fb66fb32077709a9ca38053f0274640293a14fdd22978
             Got        c77ab57a36e39ce205ca2327a3edd10399f4d78a3be91e80d845a1b97c29b7d6
```

I've searched for information about it online but nothing seems to be quite what i am experiencing, for context I had python and pip installed before and didn't have any trouble, I don't use python regularly so  I don't know since when this has happened, also worth noting that I have a dual boot with windows and linux and windows has a ubuntu subsystem, all of these give me this exact problem which makes me believe that it has to do with some hardware setting, last thing I changed in my bios utility was the setting for using virtual machines, i haven't checked if this is the problem yet, but seems like taking a shot in the dark.

Any guidance would be helpful

Comment: What OS are you on? Is this Windows or Mac or Linux?

Comment: In this case I was using Linux, but it also happens for windows

Comment: I asked because on Mac, you have to install some certificates that come with the python installation. I'm not sure what's going on in your case, though.